# How to add multiple Google fonts

Tags: mediawiki

I have an old Mediawiki site (1.6.x) and I need to upgrade it to 1.31.x.

I need to add multiple Google fonts

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald)
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial)
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script)
```

The skin of my upgraded site is based on

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Skin:Example

I tried a few ways, but none of them is working. For example, in skin.json:

```
"ResourceModules": {
    "skins.navajo": {
        "class": "ResourceLoaderSkinModule",
        "styles": {
            "resources/libraries/normalise.css": {
                "media": "screen"
            },
            "resources/screen-common.less": {
                "media": "screen"
            },
            "https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald": {
                "media": "screen"
            },
```

I also included the above three fonts in screen-common.less. Not working either.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working by using OutputPage::addStyle in skins code.

```
$out->addStyle("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald", "screen");
$out->addStyle("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Questrial", "screen");
$out->addStyle("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dancing+Script", "screen");
```